# Find a difference between 2 tables

Tags: postgresql

I want to check that the poi_equipement table (relationship table) corresponds to the data in the data table (i.e. a two-way check)

https://dbfiddle.uk/gFMjbIpX

detect that wc (in poi_equipement) is extra (because it is not present in the data table) and that hotel is not in poi_equipement so it is absent compared to the data table

I don't understand why with the raquête except he just answers me hotel.
I want him to answer me hotel and wc.

```
select object from data where subject = 'url1'
except
select subject from poi_equipement inner join equipement on poi_equipement.equipement_id = equipement.id;
```

ideally I want to know when I have a difference in poi_equipement, in data or in the 2 tables

Comment: What you describe is a many-to-many (M:M) between `poi_equipement:correspondence` with `datatable` as the resolution table. Generally you would **would not** expect a 100% correspondence in `dataatable`. The approach taken with `select ... except select ...` is the appropriate one, but without actual table definitions (ddl) it not possible to see exactly what you need. Post the actual ddl and your expected results, all as text --**no images**. You should take a few minuets and review [ask]

Comment: on one side I have data and on the other side I have data. I just want to check that poi_equipement is equal to the data in data in fact

Comment: Post your ddl, and if not in the definition then post foreign key definitions as well. We cannot answer your question properly without it.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/fWgB_-Ud here I want to detect that 'wc' is not in the data list and I want to detect that hotel is missing in poi_equipement. I therefore want to detect when poi_equipement is not equal to data

Comment: here I think it's + actually understandable with the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full outer join will do

```sql
with params as (
select 'url1' as subject),
data_object as (
select d.object
  from data d
  join params prm
    on d.subject = prm.subject),
equipment_subject as (    
select e.subject
  from poi_equipement pe 
  join poi p
    on pe.poi_id = p.id
  join equipement e 
    on pe.equipement_id = e.id 
  join params prm
    on p.id_url = prm.subject)
select d.object    as data,
       e.subject   as poi_equipment
  from data_object d
  full outer
  join equipment_subject e
    on d.object = e.subject
 where d.object is null
    or e.subject is null;
```

Result:

```
data |poi_equipment|
-----+-------------+
hotel|             |
     |wc           |
```

You can remove `where` clause if you need to see which item is in both places.